# Get the Application Pool Identity programmatically

Tags: c#, iis, application-pool, applicationpoolidentity

How do I get the identity of an appPool programmatically in C#? I want the application pool user and NOT the user who is currently logged in.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You could use `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` to identify the Identity in which the current application is running. [This link](http://netpl.blogspot.com/2010/09/identity-of-application-pool-in-iis.html) provides a nice utility which displays the identity under which the aspx is run.

Comment: If I change the appPool identity in the IIS Manager shouldn't System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name get the changed value?

Comment: Ok for someone out there that might be struggling, this is the code I used to get the username that started the AppPool (it's identity):  
ApplicationPool pool = serverManager.ApplicationPools["YoutAppPoolName"];  pool.ProcessModel.IdentityType = ProcessModelIdentityType.SpecificUser;
string user = pool.ProcessModel.UserName;

Comment: @p0enkie what is `serverManager` ?

Comment: It is present in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll.  var serverManager = new ServerManager();

Answer (score 9):

You need to make a reference to Microsoft.Web.Administration (in Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll).
Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll is located in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv.

```
//Add this to your using statements:
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

//You can get the App Pool identity like this:    
public string GetAppPoolIdentity(string appPoolName)
{
    var serverManager = new ServerManager();

    ApplicationPool appPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools[appPoolName];
    appPool.ProcessModel.IdentityType = ProcessModelIdentityType.SpecificUser;
    return appPool.ProcessModel.UserName;            
}
```

Comment: I used this code and it returns blank string. What could be the reason? I have just programmatically created an application pool  and I am using the same pool name that I just created.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility that seems to work OK for me and does not require installation of the Microsoft.Web.Administration package and its legion dependencies:

```
string appPoolUserIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

From [forums.asp.net](https://forums.asp.net/t/1623599.aspx?Get%20the%20app%20pool%20identity%20user)

Comment: Nice answer, but really the same suggestion as the accepted answer, isn't it? The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10101417/1175496) says to use: `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`

Comment: It may equate to the same. I mentioned it because it seemed to be more simple to deploy without all the Using's.