# How To Discover AppPool Properties For Running Web App

Tags: c#, iis, application-pool

I would like to know how to programmatically discover and enumerate properties of the Application Pool being used to run my C# web site in order that I can test properties of the App Pool against a set of expectations and report the results. Environment is .NET 4 or later and IIS 7 or later.

I was wondering whether there are facilities built-in to the framework for this, or whether I would be dependent on an assembly present only on servers where IIS is installed.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Get the Application Pool Identity programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101162/get-the-application-pool-identity-programmatically)

Comment: I was alluding to possibly using ServerManager in Microsoft.Web.Administration to get ALL the properties of the App Pool running my site however, (a) I don't know whether this is IIS version specific, (b) what rights the account running my web site will need to enumerate this information, (c) how an app knows what its app pool is called. Looking at MSDN now, but other SO users can probably wade in and save me a whole bunch of time :-)