# Assert User.Identity.Name is set right in my MVC app

Tags: iis, application-pool

I have an ASP.NET MVC app running on IIS 7.5 with an app pool which identity is set to "roger01".

I'd like to make sure when I render `@User.Idenity.Name` it's that identity (roger01) that's displayed.

I tried using ASP impersonation but it's not compatible with Integrated mode. And ASP.NET MVC requires integrated mode.

I also set the Anonymous Authentication identity to "roger01" but it doesn't change anything.

I actually tried  lot of things for a few hours I'm not even able to enumerate...

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10101417/1085891) looks like it might accomplish what you're after.

> #### The identity of an application pool in IIS
>
> When creating a new application pool, it’s often convenient to be able to identify the
> identity the pool is using. The issue arises usually on IIS 7/7.5
> where default application pools use identities of a form **IIS
> APPPOOL\identityname**. And when you grant access to databases/file
> system you have to provide the identity name in an exact form.
>
> Usually I tend to use this simple script. Just copy it into a text
> file, name it **test.aspx** and point your browser to it. The
> application pool’s identity name will be presented to you in a clear
> way.
>
> ```
> <%@ Page Language="C#" %>
>  
> Current user: <%= System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name %>
> ```

via [Get the Application Pool Identity programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101162/get-the-application-pool-identity-programmatically)