# PrincipalContext Strange behavior

Tags: c#, active-directory

hello in my domain we have an app where domain admin logon with user/password .
for validate credential are valide i use this code.

```
 public bool IsValidDomainCredential(string user , string password)
        {
            if (password == null || user == null) { return false; }

            bool valid = false;
            using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"DWfoo.foo"))
            {

                valid = context.ValidateCredentials(user, password);
            }
            return valid;
        }
```

it worked well but this year our admin have mixed autentification smartcart and password.

and something in smartcard driver seem interact with this code cuz when it execute  it crash the application with exeption.

> System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryOperationException
>
> > The server can not handle directory requests

sometime it will not crash and ask for code PIN of the smartcard then if i don't cancel it crash again  if i cancel i can logon.

i'm afraid this will happen at any application call on active directory
and i have 0 idea how to totaly ignor smartcard driver and interaction.

Comment: Which line throws the exception? Are the `user` and `password` variables set to valid values when it happens?

Comment: valid = context.ValidateCredentials(user, password); this line yes they valid

Comment: There are a couple different answers here that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694919/nets-directory-services-throws-a-strange-exception

Comment: thanks for the link this fixed the behavior. bool valid = context.ValidateCredentials(user, pass, ContextOptions.Negotiate); not sure what it does but no more smartcard popup or error